# Line drawn with Adorner using DrawingContext.DrawLine is "blurry"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using an `Adorner` in a WPF application to render the drop point in a drag-n-drop operation.  The line should be a black line, a single pixel thick, but it ends up getting doubled and slightly gray.  I'm guessing this is somehow related to the way that WPF renders at the sub-pixel level.

The `Window` hosting the content with the `AdornerLayer` has `SnapsToDevicePixels` set to `true`, which has fixed similar issues in the past, but it doesn't seem to be affecting the `Adorner` at all.

This is the output I'm getting.  The 2 pixel thick gray line below the text *should* be 1 pixel thick and black:
[image]

The `Pen` used to draw the line is defined with:

```
_pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
```

and drawn using:

```
drawingContext.DrawLine(_pen, left, right);
```

The `AdornerLayer` is the default one present on `Window`.  If it matters at all, the `Adorner` is being applied to a `TreeView` on a `UserControl` placed in the `Window`.

What do I need to do to get this to render the way I want?

Answer (score 1):

In your adorner class, you can try some of these options and combinations of them... This is what I use in my adorner to get rid of blurry lines and blurry icons:

```
        RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(this, EdgeMode.Aliased);
        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(this, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);

        SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
        UseLayoutRounding = true;
```

Unfortunately, the answer you provided yourself is sometimes the only answer. Offsetting by 0.5, setting the brush width to 1.0001, etc. are pretty common workarounds. WPF tried to be clever by anti-aliasing, but they don't do it right for 1 pixel width / height lines and other types of elements.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with various options, I found that offsetting `left` and `right` by `.5` before calling `DrawLine` fixes the issue.  This also seems to confirm my sub-pixel theory.

```
left.Offset(5, 5);
right.Offset(5, 5);
drawingContext.DrawLine(_pen, left, right);
```

While this does work, I find it to be a very unsatisfying solution.  My drawing logic will most likely get more complex, and I don't want to constantly have to deal with half-pixel offsets.

I'm hoping that someone else can point me to a "more correct" way of handling this.